# Load a php file based on screen resolution (js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense

Trying to load different adsense ad units based on screen resolution. 
So, what I've done is , i've put different adsense units into different php files, and here is a js i'm trying to use.

```
if ($(window).width() > 1435 ) {
        $(".adinsert1").load("../addesk1.php");
        $(".adinsert2").load("../addesk2.php");
        $(".adinsert3").load("../addesk3.php");
    }
     else  {
        $(".adinsert1").load("../admob1.php");
        $(".adinsert2").load("../admob2.php");
        $(".adinsert3").load("../admob3.php");
     }
```

And it doesn't display anything

Comment: Is there a question that goes with this?

Comment: Oh yeah... it doesn't show ads

Comment: provide us with your HTML/CSS/Javascript in a jsfiddle

Comment: Look in the browser debugger and see what `.load()` is actually getting back from PHP.

Comment: Check to make sure you're using a fully qualified url in your JavaScript - it knows nothing of your server.

Answer (score 0):

You must first check the AdSense policies and see whether your site fulfills all their expectations. Next, you must make sure that you wait for a few minutes after you have first integrated the system. If you still have a problem, then you should contact AdSense for information. You should check whether Javascript is enabled in the browser you are testing at and that there are no Javascript errors. Also, make sure that your code for displaying AdSense ads is accurate. Last, but not least, make sure that your JS function called `load` requests the server correctly, it gets the correct response and the response is correctly displayed.

Comment: Once again, the ad unit does get impressions. It's just it's getting very little of them.